# !Empty condition always gets false

Tags: php, html

i am having trouble in checking if a form field is empty and redirecting it to a particular location depending on whether the if condition is true or false.
The problem is even after filling all the fields the 2nd if condition always becomes false and popup.php page gets opened.
 This is my php code :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['YourName']) && isset($_POST['EmailID']) && isset($_POST['ContactNumber']) && isset($_POST['Destination']) && isset($_POST['ModeTransport']) && isset($_POST['DateTravel']) && isset($_POST['DateReturn']) && isset($_POST['Accommodation']) && isset($_POST['Choice1']) && isset($_POST['Choice2']) && isset($_POST['Adults']) && isset($_POST['Child']) && isset($_POST["how_to_reach_you"]))

    $YourName=$_POST['YourName'];
    $EmailID=$_POST['EmailID'];
    $ContactNumber=$_POST['ContactNumber'];
    $Destination=$_POST['Destination'];
    $ModeTransport=$_POST['ModeTransport'];
    $DateTravel=$_POST['DateTravel'];
    $DateReturn=$_POST['DateReturn'];
    $Accommodation=$_POST['Accommodation'];
    $Choice1=$_POST['Choice1'];
    $Choice2=$_POST['Choice2'];
    $Adults=$_POST['Adults'];
    $Child=$_POST['Child'];
    $via=$_POST["how_to_reach_you"];

if(!empty($YourName) && !empty($EmailID) && !empty($ContactNumber) && !empty($Destination) && !empty($ModeTransport) && !empty($DateTravel) && !empty($DateReturn) && !empty($Accommodation) && !empty($Choice1) && !empty($Choice2) && !empty($Adults) && !empty($Child))

    if($via=="Email me")

        header("Location:email.php");

    else

        header("Location:call.php");

else

    header("Location:popup.php");

?>
```

Comment: That's a mess, you know you can do `isset($var1, $var2, $var3)` right instead of all those and's.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php, as for the empty you could do `$post = array_filter($_POST)` and then `if(count($post) == count($_POST))`

Comment: din't know it, thanks but thats not the problem i am facing

Comment: yea because this `if($via=="Email me") .. else ... else` is invalid syntax so... yea.  Your only allowed one `else` per if.

Comment: no the second else is for the if checking the !empty condition

Comment: That's possible, but it's such a mess how can I tell?  some brackets would go a long way.

Comment: You do know PHP treats, `0, '0', false and ''` as empty right?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: yes i know that

Comment: what does `var_dump($_POST)` say...  If conditions don't lie.  Your inputs are either incorrect, misspelled or contain an empty value.

Comment: isset is also largely irrelevant, because only form elements of checkbox or radio will be not set, assuming you have all the form elements on the page that is.  The rest of the elements will submit an empty string, or in the case of a select the first value.

Comment: $_POST["how_to_reach_you"]; is a radio button

Answer (score 0):

well as I said isset is irrelevant, and to handle the empty I would do this

```
  $via = (isset($_POST["how_to_reach_you"]) ? $_POST["how_to_reach_you"] : false;
  unset($_POST["how_to_reach_you"]);
  $post = array_filter($_POST); 

if( count($post) == count($_POST)){
    if($via=="Email me"){
        header("Location:email.php");
    }else{
        header("Location:call.php");
    }
}else{
    header("Location:popup.php");
}
```

None of those values are used in this code, and with a redirect they are pointless.  Array filter removes empty elements from the array, so by using it you can check the count on the original and the filtered version to tell if any elements are empty.  If there are empty values the `$post` will be less the the `$_POST`. Your not checking the `how_to_reach_you` value fo

if you still need to declare all those variables you can use

```
 extract($post);
```

Which will create variables with the same name as the array keys.

Comment: so what you are saying is I only check if isset for the radio button while declare all other variables directly and then try out your code to check if empty???

Comment: Why declare them if they are not used? if the radio has a default value why check it?  Of course this might not be the complete code but I dont know that, you could do `extract($post)`;  http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: i have two radio buttons. I want to redirect to a particular page depending on which radio button is checked so the check. The check is working fine when i remove the if checking !empty. So the problem was that when i add the !empty condition it was always getting false and redirecting to popup.php

Comment: obviously that is because something is empty or not spelled correctly,  empty and if conditions dont lie...  if they did the thousands of servers that use php would know that.